# Setting reminders and check condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c

It may be simple but i am looking for a specific solution inside a problem.

I would like to let user set a reminder ,but when the time is come, to check some condition in my server before i show him the notification message .

Also, i would like to have the ability to cancel all reminders in one line.

Right now i am using the notification alarm like this :

```
 UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                    notification.fireDate = newDate;
                    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
                    notification.alertTitle=@"Reminder";
                    notification.alertBody = message;
                    notification.soundName=@"shake.mp3";
                     notification.userInfo=med;
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]   scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

and cancel all of them with this :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

If the user hit the message i have a callback function. but i would like to check **before** i show the message-for a condition.

How do you set a reminder that fires a callback function,so you can also control the reminders,the specific messages,the condition of the app when user hit the message ( background/foreground etc)  ?

Comment: This is not possible with `UILocalNotification`. You might want to use push notifications instead.

Comment: @Adam Push notification occurs by outside trigger(Server) i don't want that. The user should set inside the app a time for a notification , and when the time is come- i would like to check something before i show the message. There is no way to schedule some task for specific time in iOS??

Comment: No it is not. You want to check stuff server side before showing your notification, push notifications seem to be the perfect solution for that kind of task.

Comment: @Adam thanks but are you actually reading what i am writing ? the USER should be able to set INSIDE the app a specific times for events. Is it possible with push notifications ???

Comment: Yes I am reading what you are writing and yes, it is possible with push notifications.

Comment: @Adam, i am not sure you are right at all, from the Apple docs: "A local notification is scheduled and sent by the app itself. Remote notifications—also known as push notifications—arrive from outside a device or a Mac. They originate on a remote server"

Comment: @Adam if what you suggest is to register each and every user notification on the server, and then handle all my users notifications from the server, so this is not a solution to the presented problem at all, and moreover, its not efficient at all . Unless you are Evernote, with tons of servers in hand.

Comment: You can use your server for that. When the user adds a notification, store the data server side and write server side code to do the rest. This way you can achieve your conditional behaviour. Simple as that. Remote notifications are originated from APNS server, but that doesn't mean they can't be added from client device.

Comment: @Adam I knew it.. well, this is really not what i asked at all(!). Its like telling someone, i have a solution for you, go get a F16 to solve your car problem. This needs to be scheduled inside the app in a simple way.  thanks anyway..

Comment: What you asked for is not possible. I said that in my first comment. I have provided you a solution that would work and it is not that complicated IMO. You might not like it, but it is the only way to meet your requirements.